# beeline msck repair table returns Nonzero exit value 127

Tags: hive, beeline

My script is

```
 beeline <<EOF 
 !connect -u jdbc:hive://someurl; principal=hive/someprincipal;set hive.msck.repair.batch.size=10000; msck repair table default.test_table sync partitions;
          EOF
```

Script returns Nonzero exit value 127.
The problem is located at last part: msck repair table default.test_table sync partitions.

May be msck requires some more syntax inside beeline scripts?

Comment: Have you tried instead `beeline -u jdbc://... -e "msck..."`. Or even use external script with `-f`? 
 In other words, why are you trying to use bash redirection? Has that worked before?

Comment: Yes, I also used -e "msck...". And with the same error as a result